# adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is not working for my custom Adapter (extended from BaseAdapter)

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

Please Check the following codes & please tell me about the error(s) I have done. Its not refreshing the list by using notifyDataSetChanged()

While clicking the refresh button the list becomes either blank or it has no change.

The code is like this:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where adapter is my adapter type extended from BaseAdapter. Please give a solution asap.

If you wish, you may check following codes I have done, to find the errors.

Comment: In the future, you should try to isolate your problem and then post the code you think is causing your problem. It's easier for everyone to help you out, by not having to read through every line, and you're more likely to get an answer if you aren't posting a code dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No need of further discussion on this issue**.

**I get solved** this issue. [**Click here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228698/no-change-black-screen-by-notifydatasetchanged) to check the solution.