# no change/black screen by notifyDataSetChanged();

Tags: android, listview, adapter, baseadapter

I want to do something like this.

while pressing the *refresh* button, it will refresh the list. Activity codes are like this:

```
        adapter = new TweetAdapter(Welcome.this, tweets, users);
        tweetsList.setAdapter(adapter);


    private void refreshAdapter() {
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.refresh(tweets, users);
    }
```

`refreshAdapter()` called when I need to change the list item. here `tweets` & `users` are `ArrayList` & `HashMap` items

and the adapter part is like this:

```
public void clear() {
    this.tweets.clear();
    this.users.clear();
}

public void refresh(ArrayList<Tweet> tweets, HashMap<String, User> users) {
    this.tweets.addAll(tweets);
    this.users.putAll(users);
    Collections.sort(this.tweets, new TweetTimeComparator());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

but unfortunately `notifyDataSetChanged();` is not working. by clicking *refresh* the list either turns black(maximum time) or have no response(some time).

please tell me if you find the error or suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are clearing the data

```
this.tweets.clear();
this.users.clear();
```

..
I think as tweets and users both has same refreance ( as passed from activity to adapter ) so both tweets  and both users (on adapter  and on activity are pointing to same ArrayLists) so both are get-clear so these line not make sense as both are empty

```
this.tweets.addAll(tweets);
this.users.putAll(users);
```

try

```
public TweetAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Tweet> tweets, HashMap<String, User> users) { 

mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); 
this.tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>(); 
this.users = new HashMap<String, User>();

this.tweets.addAll(tweets);
this.users.putAll(users);

Collections.sort(this.tweets, new TweetTimeComparator()); 
}
```

..

```
public void refresh(ArrayList<Tweet> tweets, HashMap<String, User> users) {

  this.tweets.clear();
    this.users.clear();

    this.tweets.addAll(tweets);
    this.users.putAll(users);
    Collections.sort(this.tweets, new TweetTimeComparator());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

but NOTE : now reference to both tweets (on adapter  and on activity) and both users (on adapter  and on activity) are different.

There should no direct assignment like adapter.tweets = activity.tweets any where other use this.tweets.addAll(tweets);

Comment: so what to do ?? this.users.clear(); is not too much important because I can use old user-sets but this.tweets.clear(); is important for refreshing new tweets.

Comment: `public TweetAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Tweet> tweets,
   HashMap<String, User> users) {
  mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  this.tweets = tweets;
  this.users = users;
  Collections.sort(this.tweets, new TweetTimeComparator());
 }`

Comment: yes ... you are right. just debugged & found both are empty :(

Comment: Thank you my friend, its working. Just twitted & get refreshed with the new tweet :) Actually I have done a basic and big mistake not doing `this.tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();` and so on... thanks again.

Comment: something more probs... while refreshing it doubles the tweets. i.e. same tweet 2 times. again refreshing same tweets 3 times :(

Comment: have you uses putAll from any where else ?

Comment: putAll both in constructor & refresh() as like addAll

Comment: he he.. at last its done. you can't imagine where I found the bug, actually its not possible from remotely.   

tweets value doubles/triples from the activity where it downloads the new tweets. I just added tweets.clear() before adding new fresh set of tweets in the activity & then passed it via clear() then refresh(). else everything is ok. the clear() in adapter is working, and I already thanked you for this.tweets=new ArrayList<Tweet>(); Thanks again for trying to solve my problem.